Can I use file:// in markdown?
I'm trying to link to a folder on a network directory in a markdown document, but it doesn't seem to be working.
[folder](file://///server/folder/)
This file address works from a browser, so I know it is a correct uri. Is there another format I'm supposed to use ?

What is rendering your markdown? If this document is hosted on github, I don't think it will render to a proper link.

This is not a Markdown issue. Browsers, for years, have been actively blocking access to UNC paths.
